# how to add a list of all the clients connected on a chat application in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, chat, tcp

I found this Client-Server chat code online but would like to modified it to show the list of clients connected to to each client this way users know who is connected and who has left the chat.

client class:

```
package edu.lmu.cs.networking;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author PUTA
 * The client follows the Chat Protocol which is as follows.
 * When the server sends "SUBMITNAME" the client replies with the
 * desired screen name.  The server will keep sending "SUBMITNAME"
 * requests as long as the client submits screen names that are
 * already in use.  When the server sends a line beginning
 * with "NAMEACCEPTED" the client is now allowed to start
 * sending the server arbitrary strings to be broadcast to all
 * chatters connected to the server.  When the server sends a
 * line beginning with "MESSAGE " then all characters following
 * this string should be displayed in its message area.
 */
public class ChatClient {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("InstantMessenger");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

    /**
     * Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
     * listener with the textfield so that pressing Return in the
     * listener sends the textfield contents to the server.  Note
     * however that the textfield is initially NOT editable, and
     * only becomes editable AFTER the client receives the NAMEACCEPTED
     * message from the server.
     */
    public ChatClient() {

        // Layout GUI
        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
        frame.pack();

        // Add Listeners
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /**
             * Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield by sending
             * the contents of the text field to the server.    Then clear
             * the text area in preparation for the next message.
             */
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the address of the server.
     */
    private String getServerAddress() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
            "Welcome to the Chatter",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
     */
    private String getName() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Choose a screen name:",
            "Screen name selection",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
     */
    private void run() throws IOException {

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

server class:

```
package edu.lmu.cs.networking;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;
/**
 *
 *  
 */
public class ChatServer {
        /**
     * The port that the server listens on.
     */
    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    /**
     * The set of all names of clients in the chat room.  Maintained
     * so that we can check that new clients are not registering name
     * already in use.
     */
    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    /**
     * The set of all the print writers for all the clients.  This
     * set is kept so we can easily broadcast messages.
     */
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    /**
     * The appplication main method, which just listens on a port and
     * spawns handler threads.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A handler thread class.  Handlers are spawned from the listening
     * loop and are responsible for a dealing with a single client
     * and broadcasting its messages.
     */
    private static class Handler extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        /**
         * Constructs a handler thread, squirreling away the socket.
         * All the interesting work is done in the run method.
         */
        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        /**
         * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a
         * screen name until a unique one has been submitted, then
         * acknowledges the name and registers the output stream for
         * the client in a global set, then repeatedly gets inputs and
         * broadcasts them.
         */
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Create character streams for the socket.
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
                // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
                // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
                // must be done while locking the set of names.
                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in.readLine();
                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (names) {
                        if (!names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
                // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
                // this client can receive broadcast messages.
                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
                writers.add(out);

                // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
                // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
                // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
                if (name != null) {
                    names.remove(name);
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as a new client connects put that in an ArrayList(online) and when the client closes the socket, just before that write a message to the server that the client goes out and remove that from the list then.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be, to introduce a command like `:WHO`. When client send `:WHO` to the server, the server will respond list of user's connected.

Something like (on the server class) :

```
String input = in.readLine();
if (input == null) {
    return;
} else if(input.equals(":WHO")) {
    out.println(names.toString()); // ... or format it nicer.
} else {
    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
    }
}
```

This way, the client can ask "who's login/online" any time. Or you can send list of `names` when the client first established a connection, and send only names who joins or parts the chat.